# Mysqli Delete function dosent work

Tags: php, mysqli

i running into some problems when i trying to delete from database useing mysqli

here is my code

```
function delete() {
    // get id value
    $delete = $_GET['delete'];
    // delete the entry
    $query = mysqli_query($dblogin, "delete from admin where id=$delete");
    // redirect back to the view page
    header("Location: users.php");
    }
    if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {
    delete();
    }
```

wil some one take a look on it, and help me out :D

Comment: Where exactly is `$dblogin` defined? Have you tried `mysqli_query($dblogin, "DELETE FROM admin WHERE id="delete") or die(mysqli_error());`?

Comment: `$dblogin` is not defined within the scope of that function.

Comment: remove $dblogin, just add the query

Comment: Try printing the "delete from" query line to the browser to help yourself with identifying the problem. Also make sure that if your $_GET['delete'] variable is a string, that is has a set of quotes around it.

Comment: The config file is included in the session checker script, where dblogin is defined, i use dblogin in that script more than once :/

Comment: I was going to say "You're missing a bracket, and this function is recursive which must be a mistake." But no, its just bad indenting and Egyptian brackets combined to create an optical illusion.

Comment: @ Yair : with the mysqli_ extension you cannot skip the resource handle as with the deprecated mysql_ extension.

Comment: @ Oliver Vonschmidt : have a read of http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php regarding `in the session checker script, where dblogin is defined`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You forgot to set the parameter called $delete.

```
function delete($dblogin, $delete) {
  // delete the entry
  $query = mysqli_query($dblogin, "delete from admin where id=$delete");
  // redirect back to the view page
  header("Location: users.php");
}

if (isset($_GET['delete']) || !empty(GET['delete'])) {
  delete($dblogin, $_GET['delete']); // call the function
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the anwsers, it works like a charm :)! <3